# JQGrid zebra striping issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have just started with jQuery. I am trying to implement zebra striping in my jqGrid class. I am having the problem when user clicks on sort column, all rows get rearranged and the zebra striping is blown away.

Zebra Striping code

```
 $("#item_table tbody tr:odd").addClass("alt");
 $("#item_table tbody tr").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("over");
 });
 $("#item_table tbody tr").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("over");
 });
```

jqGrid code

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
  autowidth: true,
  hidegrid: false,
  colModel:[
   { name: 'icon', index: 'icon', width: 0, resizable: false },
   { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 0, resizable: false },
   { name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 0, sorttype: "int", resizable: false }
  ],
  onSortCol: function(index, iCol, sortorder) {
                 // This doesn't work - IT SHOULDN'T EITHER, since event is called 
                 // just after clicking to sort but before actual sorting
                 jQuery("#item_table tbody tr:odd").addClass("odd");
  },
  caption: "Item Table"
 });
```

I also tried loadComplete, gridComplete events, but to no avail.

How should I proceed with this? Have I even started this right?

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `altRows` and `altclass` attributes options from their [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Aoptions)

Comment: Same problem still exists. When I sort, the zebra stripes get intermixed and even if I reload the grid on event onSortCol, the sort order won't be retained upon reload.